# S3 bucket policy to make only certain file types publicly readable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We run a shop where music can be downloaded.

In the bucket we have folders representing each tune with a certain number and inside the folder we have various file formats.

To pre-listen the file is stored in the mp3 format.

Currently we manually select the mp3 files and give them read access to anyone (World).

But this should be possible too with a bucket policy as well, i.e., every mp3 that is being uploaded will have read access by anyone.

But the policy we created with the policy generator does not work...

Any ideas?

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1541353430646",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1541353373980",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": "mp3"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `prefix` means the **beginning** of a name, so that won't work.

Instead, change the `Resource` to match your ending:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*.mp3"
        }
    ]
}
```

This also works for objects in sub-directories.

Comment: policiy requires also the principal which is everyone "*" in our case. Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: Oops! Yes, sorry -- I tested it as an IAM policy, which didn't need a Principal. You would need to add it for a Bucket Policy.

Comment: Could the same be done in reverse? For instance, to allow access of all file types EXCEPT for *.mp3? So in effect switching "Effect" from "Allow" to "Deny" ?

Comment: @Chris You would first need to Allow access to everything (`*`), then Deny access to `*.mp3`. Please note that filename extensions don't guarantee the actual content of a file (for example, it could be a Word documents saved with a .mp3 suffix).